# How to work with NugetPackage and LocalProject at same time?

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.8

I got an issue working with Nuget packages and local projects.

I am working on a .Net Framework solution, with many projects and many of them are packaged with Nuget in a private repository. I am using PackageReferences to resolve nuget packages. I am working on solution with that kind of dependency tree.

- StartUpProject

  - Project1(LocalProject)

    - Project2 v1.0.0(NugetPackage)

      - Project3 v1.0.0(NugetPackage)
  - Project3 v1.0.1(LocalProject)

When I want to debug or upgrade functionality of packaged project, I remove Nuget package and add that assembly as local project.

When I am navigating in the source code if I try to go to some function from the modified project, Visual Studio open the code as external assembly and does not resolve like local project.

Maybe the problem is other Nuget package (Project2) depends from I removed Nuget package (Project3) and Visual Studio still resolving that assembly as Nuget package.

The error that Visual Studio throws at compilation is [CS0433](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0433)): The type 'MyType' exist in both'Project3 , Version=1.0.0, ...' and in 'Project3, Version=1.0.1, ...'

What is way to work in that cases?
Is any way to force to use local project than dependency nuget package?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the **complete** error message. You should be able to copy and paste it into the **question**.

Comment: The error message is on the post: CS0433: The type 'MyType' exist in both 'Project3 , Version=1.0.0, ...' and in 'Project3, Version=1.0.1, ...', I just simplify names and I remove culture and plublic token.